# SQLite CASE query with multiple conditions

Tags: sql, sqlite, case

I am trying to execute a query to find the minimum price of various products in the same store in the same week

When I only have two products, the query is working perfectly fine.

When I have 3 or more products I am doing something wrong, but do not know what.

This is what I use for two products (works fine) :

```
 select a.* , b.*,

 case when a.preis_pro_unze < b.preis_pro_unze then a.preis_pro_unze 
    when b.preis_pro_unze < a.preis_pro_unze then b.preis_pro_unze

end as minpreis

 FROM Heinz32_36 as a, Heinz32_36 as b 
WHERE
a.IRI_KEY = b.IRI_KEY 
AND a.week = b.week
AND a.UPC_DESC != b.UPC_DESC
```

This is what I tried for three products (does not work):

```
Select a.UPC_DESC, a.IRI_KEY , a.WEEK , a.Price_per_unit, a.Preis_pro_unze, 
b.UPC_DESC, b.IRI_KEY , b.WEEK , b.Price_per_unit, b.Preis_pro_unze, 
c.UPC_DESC, c.IRI_KEY , c.WEEK , c.Price_per_unit, c.Preis_pro_unze, 
case 
when min(min(a.preis_pro_unze , b.preis_pro_unze , c.preis_pro_unze )) = a.preis_pro_unze then a.preis_pro_unze
when min(min(a.preis_pro_unze , b.preis_pro_unze , c.preis_pro_unze )) = b.preis_pro_unze then b.preis_pro_unze
when min(min(a.preis_pro_unze , b.preis_pro_unze , c.preis_pro_unze )) = c.preis_pro_unze then c.preis_pro_unze

end as minpreis

FROM "prv24" as a , "prv24" as b, "prv24" as c

WHERE 

a.IRI_KEY = b.IRI_KEY = c.IRI_KEY AND
a.week = b.week = c.week AND

a.UPC_DESC  != b.UPC_DESC or a.UPC_DESC  != c.UPC_DESC
OR 
b.UPC_DESC != c.UPC_DESC
```

LIMIT 10

It Could be something with the "!=" conditions at the very end. I already tried to rewrite it with some bracket-statements but that didn´t do the job either.

I am working with SQLite. I do not get any error-messages, but the query is processing endlessly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without sample data and a schema, it's hard to be certain, but I *think* you're missing some brackets. The `OR` condition means that your query is evaluating all your `AND` conditions, and *then* adding the `OR` condition in addition; that probably leads to a huge data set, which would explain the endless processing.

```
Select a.UPC_DESC, 
       a.IRI_KEY , 
       a.WEEK , 
       a.Price_per_unit, 
       a.Preis_pro_unze, 
       b.UPC_DESC, 
       b.IRI_KEY , 
       b.WEEK , 
       b.Price_per_unit, 
       b.Preis_pro_unze, 
       c.UPC_DESC, 
       c.IRI_KEY , 
       c.WEEK , 
       c.Price_per_unit, 
       c.Preis_pro_unze, 
       case 
          when min(min(a.preis_pro_unze , b.preis_pro_unze , c.preis_pro_unze )) = a.preis_pro_unze then a.preis_pro_unze
         when min(min(a.preis_pro_unze , b.preis_pro_unze , c.preis_pro_unze )) = b.preis_pro_unze then b.preis_pro_unze
         when min(min(a.preis_pro_unze , b.preis_pro_unze , c.preis_pro_unze )) = c.preis_pro_unze then c.preis_pro_unze

end as minpreis

FROM "prv24" as a , 
     "prv24" as b, 
     "prv24" as c

WHERE 

a.IRI_KEY = b.IRI_KEY = c.IRI_KEY AND
 a.week = b.week = c.week AND

(a.UPC_DESC  != b.UPC_DESC or 
a.UPC_DESC  != c.UPC_DES  OR 
b.UPC_DESC != c.UPC_DESC)
```

However, you may find it makes *much* more sense if you use explicit join syntax and use meaningful aliases. Explicit joins avoid the problems you've just encountered (an OR condition messing up your joins), and make your code easier to read.

Here's a much neater version:

```
Select a.UPC_DESC, 
       a.IRI_KEY, 
       a.WEEK, 
       a.Price_per_unit, 
       a.Preis_pro_unze, 
       b.UPC_DESC, 
       b.IRI_KEY, 
       b.WEEK, 
       b.Price_per_unit, 
       b.Preis_pro_unze, 
       c.UPC_DESC, 
       c.IRI_KEY , 
       c.WEEK , 
       c.Price_per_unit, 
       c.Preis_pro_unze, 
       case 
          when min(min(a.preis_pro_unze , b.preis_pro_unze , c.preis_pro_unze )) = a.preis_pro_unze then a.preis_pro_unze
          when min(min(a.preis_pro_unze , b.preis_pro_unze , c.preis_pro_unze )) = b.preis_pro_unze then b.preis_pro_unze
          when min(min(a.preis_pro_unze , b.preis_pro_unze , c.preis_pro_unze )) = c.preis_pro_unze then c.preis_pro_unze
        end as minpreis 
FROM "prv24" as a 
      inner join  "prv24" as b
          on a.IRI_KEY = b.IRI_KEY
          and a.week = b.week
      inner join "prv24" as c
          on a.IRI_KEY = c.IRI_KEY
          and a.week = c.week
WHERE 
(a.UPC_DESC  != b.UPC_DESC or 
a.UPC_DESC  != c.UPC_DES  or 
b.UPC_DESC != c.UPC_DESC)
```

Comment: @NevillieKuyt . . . You would be more likely to get upvotes if you fixed the query formatting and taught the OP how to write a decent query . . . in particular, proper `JOIN` syntax and meaningful table aliases.